# Проблема с осью X в d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

У меня есть график с помощью d3js только ось X не до конца рисует. Подскажите что не так и как исправить чтобы ось X рисовалась правильно до конца?

Вот код

```
import * as d3 from 'd3';

const data = [
    { id: 1, value: 1 },
    { id: 2, value: 15 },
    { id: 3, value: 2 },
    { id: 4, value: 20 },
    { id: 5, value: 4 },
    { id: 6, value: 8 }
];

const width = 900;
const height = 400;

const chart = d3.select('body')
    .append('svg')
    .attr('id', 'chart')
    .attr("viewBox", [0, 0, width, height])

const margin = ({ top: 10, right: 730, bottom: 20, left: 30 });

const x = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain(data.map(d => (d.id)))
    .range([margin.left, width - margin.right]);

const y = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, d3.max(data, d => d.value)]).nice()
    .range([height - margin.bottom, margin.top])

const xAxis = g => g
    .attr("transform", `translate(0,${height - margin.bottom})`)
    .call(d3.axisBottom(x))
    .call(g => g.select(".domain").remove())

const yAxis = g => g
    .attr("transform", `translate(${margin.left},0)`)
    .call(d3.axisLeft(y).ticks(width / 30).tickSizeOuter(0))
    .call(g => g.select(".domain"))
    .call(g => g.selectAll(".tick line").clone()
        .attr("stroke-opacity", d => d === 0 ? null : 0.2)
        .attr("x2", width - margin.left - margin.right))
    .call(d3.axisLeft(y)
        .tickValues(d3.ticks(...y.domain(), 20)))

const line = d3.line()
    .x(d => x(d.id))
    .y(d => y(d.value));

chart.append("g")
    .call(yAxis);

chart.append("g")
    .call(xAxis);

chart.append("path")
    .datum(data)
    .attr("fill", "none")
    .attr("stroke", "steelblue")
    .attr("stroke-width", 2)
    .attr("stroke-linejoin", "round")
    .attr("stroke-linecap", "round")
    .attr("d", line)
```

Результат
[image: Результат работы]

если изменяю margin.right то получается вот так
[image: график измененный]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the **margin.right** value:

```
const x = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain(data.map(d => (d.id)))
    .range([margin.left, width - margin.right]);
```

Your **range** is actually 30 to 170

Comment: я изменил значение margin.right до 40 и у меня ось X растянулось до конца, но только есть проблема то что ось заканчивается на значение 2 а не на 6 как должно